# duda transacciones entre objetos diferentes java

Tags: java, poo, transacciones

estoy intentando desarrollar un pequeño ejemplo de lo que entendi de programacion orientada a objetos con JAVA, pero tengo una duda, tengo dos objetos: TRAMITE Y SOLICITUD el tramite tiene una relacion con solicitud,
tengo un metodo en el que se llama agregarTramite y otro que se llama agregarSolicitud, en cada uno utilizo un prepareStatement. Lo que necesito es que al agregar un tramite nuevo se agregue una solicitud nueva. no se como jutnar las dos transacciones

Creo una instancia del tramite:

```
Tramite nuevoTramite = newTramite();
nuevoTramite.agregarTramite();
```

y dentro del metodo agregarTramite creo una instancia de la solicitud para que se inserte el registro en la base de datos

```
class Tramite(){
public boolean agregarTramite(){
..
..
 PreparedStatement agregarNuevaSolicitud = 
 conection.prepareStatement(nuevaSolicitudQuery);
 agregarTramite.setTimestamp(1, Fecha.fechaActual());
..
..
    Solicitud nuevaSolicitud = new Solicitud();
    nuevaSolicitud.agregarNuevaSolicitud();
    conection.commit();
    stmt.close();
    conection.close();
..
..
}
```

pero creo que esto esta mal, como puedo utilizar un commit para transacciones que se encuentran en clases diferentes, es eso posible? espero me puedan ayudar.

Muchas Gracias